# Why td (CustomerID) background color doesn't change

Tags: jquery

I want to change CustomerID background color if it empty.

```
<table width="200px" border="0" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="1">
    <tr>
        <td id="CustomerID"></td> 
        <td id="GroupID"></td>
    </tr>
</table>

if($("#CustomerID").text().trim() == "") 
{   
    $("#CustomerID").css("background-color","yellow");  
}
```

Comment: "j" at the end of the first line of the "if" statement?

Answer (score 0):

Your code is correct, the only mistake is you've added a 'j' after your if statement. Take it off and you're set. You can have a couple more options to access the content of the `<td>` tag.

To get the text content

```
document.getElementById ( "#CustomerID" ).innerText
```

or

If you can use jQuery then you can use

```
$("#CustomerID").text();
```

To get the HTML content

```
var tdElem = document.getElementById ( "tdid" );
var tdText = tdElem.innerHTML;
```

In jQuery

```
$("#CustomerID").html();
```

View it on jsbin:  [here](http://jsbin.com/ruvudesipe/edit?html,output)

Comment: @KarimAli Make sure you've added the jQuery library at the top. Here's a screenshot I took so you can look at it here, hope this helsp!: http://imgur.com/cAqCUbW

Comment: You have added 2 in the second td that is why it is working in your case.